# How to update entity by two fields?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, citus

Maybe some one know.
I want to use citusdb and I try to rewrite doctrine updates.
If I use standard update for entity
For example

```
$order = $repository->find(1);
$human->setComment("test");
$entityManager->flush();
```

This code create query
`Updates` orders`SET`comment `= "test" WHERE id = 1;`

For sharding in citusdb I choosed **used_id** field. This field exist in all tables.

I need to receive `Updates` orders`SET`comment `= "test" WHERE id = 1 and user_id = 5;`

I tried to add

```
$order = $repository->find(1);
$human->setComment("test");
$human->setUserId(5);
$entityManager->flush();
```

But if user_id not change doctrine remove this field from sql.

I read about preUpdate, prePost events in doctrine, maybe this can help to resolve my task. But I don't know how=(